# How to use reinforcement learning models MDP Q-learning?

Tags: model, reinforcement-learning

I am interested in studying reinforcement learning, in particular how to use RL for dynamic pricing. I tried to read some papers about it, and most of the time I see examples where authors try to simulate the environment in order to see the best options.

1. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.09967.pdf RL for fair dynamic pricing
2. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1210269 - Reinforcement learning applications in dynamic pricing of retail markets

I am trying to understand, in this case every time we have some sort of uncertainty it is possible to simulate the environment to get the answer. And every time we have new input (environment and state is different) we run the program go get the results? Is it possible to deploy the RL model?

I would really appreciate any information/links related to RL in dynamic pricing and how it is possible to use/reuse the RL models.

Comment: RL assumes you have some way to simulate the environment. The idea is that the RL agent "plays the game" in the simulated environment many times, and in doing so it learns how to play well. I'm not sure what you mean "every time we have new input (environment and state is different)" -- if the *state* changes, you don't rerun (i.e., retrain the model). If the *environment* changes -- for ex., the pricing structure or demand distribution changes -- then you need to retrain. But if the environment changes meaning you move to a new state in the same environment, you don't retrain.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 Thank you very much for your answer, I am trying to understand the main concept of RL, but I think I am confusing RL with supervised learning. 
In supervised learning we train the model and next we can it use to classify new data input (example: cat/dog, positive/negative and so on). We use this model for new data input.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 In RL, suppose I want to predict the best price for a product service. In this case, I have to simulate the "real world:, suppose I have information how much my competitors are charging for the similar products, i can estimate the demand for the product and so on. Finally, I will get the results - what would be the best price that can increase my revenue the most, for example, I have to charge 23$ for my product and with this price I get the biggest revenue. There is no need to deploy the model or something like this - I just have an answer, right? 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would describe your example this way: You have a simulator of the real world. For any action you take (e.g., for any price you set), the simulator simulates the demands, your competitors' actions, etc., over a multi-time-period horizon. The RL agent plays the game repeatedly and learns how to choose good actions in each period based on the state of the environment in each of those periods.

Comment: Multiple-period environments are the typical setup for RL. If it's just a single period, then you don't need RL, there are much simpler models for revenue optimization in that sort of setting. (Maybe that's what you meant by "no need to deploy the model"?)

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 Thank you very much for your answer! If you could recommend any tutorials/websites related to use how RL for a multi-period horizon I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Too many to mention. If you Google "reinforcement learning tutorial" you will find tones. P.S. for the sake of future users, I will move my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RL assumes you have some way to simulate the environment. The idea is that the RL agent "plays the game" in the simulated environment many times, and in doing so it learns how to play well. I'm not sure what you mean "every time we have new input (environment and state is different)" -- if the state changes, you don't rerun (i.e., retrain the model). If the environment changes -- for ex., the pricing structure or demand distribution changes -- then you need to retrain. But if the environment changes meaning you move to a new state in the same environment, you don't retrain.

For dynamic pricing, RL could work something like this: You have a simulator of the real world. For any action you take (e.g., for any price you set), the simulator simulates the demands, your competitors' actions, etc., over a multi-time-period horizon. The RL agent plays the game repeatedly and learns how to choose good actions in each period based on the state of the environment in each of those periods.

Multiple-period environments are the typical setup for RL. If it's just a single period, then you don't need RL, there are much simpler models for revenue optimization in that sort of setting.